# Android UI layout: How to create a "stacked" gallery

Tags: android, layout, gallery

I've followed the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html 
to create a basic gallery. My ultimate goal is to use a gallery as the main menu for my app but I want the images to be stacked and scrollable. I've downloaded the code for the gallery 3d app but its just too much to analyze. Eventually thats what I'll do if I dont find an easier route. Any pointers?

Comment: you mean like this http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html

Comment: i mean one on top of the other, like a deck of cards.
thank you. this seems straight to the point and simple enough to start taking apart.

Comment: ya. i would mark your comment as answer but i guess i cant mark comments as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Docs provided you a way to Arrange images like a stack. Take a look at this sample:

[Images as Stack](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html)